# Django templating language syntax for navbar notifications

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to use the Django templating language in my `Django Channels 2.1.2` project to render out any unread chat messages in a Facebook-style notification popup.

The list of unread `chatmessages` (in their respective `threads`) are not displaying because I am having trouble with the correct syntax.

This is how the front end looks. When you click the message icon, the notification disappears.

[image: inbox number] [image: notification popout]

I have a `Notification` model

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    notification_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    notification_chat = models.ForeignKey(ChatMessage, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    notification_read = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.id}'
```

navbar.html

```
 {% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <li id="notification_li" class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="notificationLink">
      <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>&nbsp; Inbox</a>
      {% for notifications in notification %}
      <span id="notification_id">{{ notifications.notification_chat }}</span>
      {% endfor %}
      <div id="notificationContainer">
            <div id="notificationTitle">Notifications</div>
            <div id="notificationsBody" class="notifications">
            {{ notification.notification_chatessage?? }}
            </div>
            <div id="notificationFooter"><a href="{% url 'chat:inbox' %}">See All</a></div>
      </div>
  </li>
```

base.html

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#notificationLink").click(function() {
        $("#notificationContainer").fadeToggle(300);
        $("#notification_id").fadeOut("slow");
        return false;
      });

      //Document Click hiding the popup
      $(document).click(function() {
        $("#notificationContainer").hide();
      });

      //Popup on click
      $("#notificationContainer").click(function() {
        return false;
      });
    });
  </script>
```

context_processors.py

```
def notification(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        notification = Notification.objects.filter(notification_user=request.user)
        return {'notification':notification}
    return Notification.objects.none()
```

I have the context processor also added into settings
in the correct place. The `notification_id` should be sent using the message WebSocket and updated each time a new message is sent (I still haven't managed to do this successfully).

consumers.py

```
async def websocket_receive(self, event):
        # when a message is received from the websocket
        print("receive", event)

        message_type = event.get('type', None)  #check message type, act accordingly
        if message_type == "notification_read":
             # Update the notification read status flag in Notification model.
             notification = Notification.object.get(id=notification_id)
             notification.notification_read = True
             notification.save()  #commit to DB
             print("notification read")

        front_text = event.get('text', None)
        if front_text is not None:
            loaded_dict_data = json.loads(front_text)
            msg =  loaded_dict_data.get('message')
            user = self.scope['user']
            username = 'default'
            if user.is_authenticated:
                username = user.username
            myResponse = {
                'message': msg,
                'username': username,
                'notification': notification_id  # send a unique identifier for the notification
            }
            ...
```

thread.html

```
   ...
      // below is the message I am receiving
      socket.onmessage = function(e) {
        var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
        // Find the notification icon/button/whatever
        // and show a red dot, add the notification_id to element as id or data attribute.
        console.log("message", e)
        var chatDataMsg = JSON.parse(e.data)
        chatHolder.append('<li>' + chatDataMsg.message + ' from ' + chatDataMsg.username + '</li>')
      }
```

In addition to helping me with this question, I would really appreciate any good learning resources.

Comment: @BearBrown Hopefully you can see what I'm trying to do!

Comment: i don't see the code where you add new notifications to the navbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For referencing the notification message, you should use `{{notifications.notification_chat.message}}`. Also, for showing all notifications, you will have to loop over all the notifications.

> navbar.html

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
              <li id="notification_li" class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="notificationLink">
                  <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>&nbsp; Inbox</a>
                  {% for notifications in notification %}

                  <span id="inbox-{{notifications.id}}">{{ notifications.notification_chat.message }}</span>

                  {% endfor %}
                  <div id="notificationContainer">
                        <div id="notificationTitle">Notifications</div>
                        <div id="notificationsBody" class="notifications">
                        {% for notifications in notification %}

                            <span id="notification-{{notifications.id}}">{{ notifications.notification_chat.message }}</span>

                        {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                        <div id="notificationFooter"><a href="{% url 'chat:inbox' %}">See All</a></div>
                  </div>
              </li>
```

I also noticed that in your `thread.html`, you are not updating the notifications when you get a response from the server. you can use the ids to to `prepend` new notifications.

Comment: Thank you so much. The message now displays in the pop out however you are right, I am not updating the notifications when I get a response from the sever so the navbar is not displaying the correct data. I'm still unclear about how to `prepend` using django channels websockets. You hinted at adding some js to the `thread.html` in your answer to my previous question but I've put it there and nothing is happening.

Comment: So `$(#notification-element).on("click", function() { data = {"type":"notification_read", "username": username, "notification_id": notification_id}; etc` goes in `thread.html` and sends that data to the `Notification` model when a message is sent? And the default is `unread`? So then on the `base.html` page the js script will need to change the `notification_id` to `read` when a user clicks on the popout?

Comment: And to clarify, a single user will have multiple `notification_chats` and thus `notification_id`s. For example, if they are in 7 different private threads, the user would be saved as an instance of `notification_user` 7 times? And the `notification_chat` field corresponds to the single `message` they have either read or not read and also the `thread`?

Comment: For first comment: Find the comment `// Find the notification icon/button/whatever`, then below that, use something like `$("#notificationContainer").prepend("<span id=...")` or `$("#notificationLink").append("<span id=...")`

Comment: Second comment: js can't update your models.. when you send the data to `websocket_receive`, then you need to update the state as already suggested. This means that until the app gets a response to the channel that a particular notification was interacted with, the system will treat it as an unread notification. So even if user reloads the page without interacting with a notification, he can see there is a ne notification for him

Comment: Third comment: Yes, for each notification for each user (to which the notification needs to be sent), there will be a new entry in the table, so that you can keep a track of which user interacted with which notification. (example a team message)

Comment: Okay so `.prepend` will simply prepend each new instance of `notification_id` (aka each time a message is received) to the `notificationLink` in the navbar for example. So does that mean there is no need to render out `{{ notification_id }}` in `navbar.html`? Also, is this correct `$("#notificationLink").prepend("<span id=notification_id")`

Comment: checkout the docs for [prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/). You need to construct html string from the server message, and then insert to the page html.

{{ notification_id }} will only render at the time of page load, so you should still pass unread notifications to template so that user knows about unread messages when he loads the page. JS will be used to add new notifications

Comment: Yes I was just on that page but I must have missed that section. Okay so that html string will carry the data such as `username` `notification_read` `message` `notification_id` etc?

Comment: html string is the html you want to render on page. in this case, all the notification `span`s

Comment: Okay, thank you. Where is `socket.send(JSON.stringify(data));` sending the data and how can I check that this script is executing?

Comment: it will send the data to your receiver - `websocket_receive`. To test it send some data and print it on server end.

Comment: Okay I will try to do that now. Also, since the sockets are now dealing with notifications as well as chats, but the ws script is only on `thread.html`, that is problematic if notifications need to be displayed across the whole site. Do I need another WS script for notifications on `base.html`?

Comment: yep..the code should be available everywhere you want client server communication.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192211/discussion-between-trilla-and-aman-garg).

Comment: Another Q...thank you in advance, so the websocket code is in base.html however when I go to any other page other than the specified websocket path `url(r"^messages/(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)",` I get the error `No route found for path` but what would the path be so that the websocket can connect on every page (because of the notifications in the navbar)?

Comment: how are you defining the websocket path in your js? something like `var socket = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.host + '/message/{{username}}/'); should work fine. Basically the websocket route needs to be correct

Comment: I'm defining it as `var endpoint = wsStart + loc.host + loc.pathname` but the problem is that the websocket needs to work on all pages because of the notifications in the navbar? Because I have this side in the base.html..I will write it below

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#notificationLink").click(function() {
        var data = {
          "type": "notification_read",
          "username": username,
          "notification_id": notification_id,
        }
        socket.send(JSON.stringify(data));`

Comment: you need to define the route such that it doesnt take `pathname`, then it will be accessible from everywhere

Comment: Okay I see, when I change it to `var endpoint = wsStart + loc.host` and change the routing to `path("", ChatConsumer),` the problem is that consumers.py takes kwargs (`username`) from the url `messages/username` and can't find them when the `url_route` is `''`

Comment: You still need to pass the username to your socket url. `var endpoint = wsStart + loc.host + "/message/{{username}}/"`. change routing accordingly